# Using Phaser, trying to tween text using Js

Tags: javascript, text, tween, phaser-framework

Cant quite figure out how to tween text using Phaser. This is my code:

```
text1 = "Home";
textStyle1 = {font: '150px Tahoma', fill:'#ffffff', align: 'center'};
textHolder1 = game.add.text(0,0,text1,textStyle1);

textTween1 = game.add.tween(text1);
textTween1.to({x:1000},5000, 'Linear',true, 0);
```

I am just trying to get the text to move.

Answer (score 0):

Your tween is currently added to the string of text. You need to instead add the tween to your `Phaser.Text` object, `textHolder1`.

```
var textTween1 = game.add.tween(textHolder1);
textTween1.to({ x: 1000 }, 5000, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true, 0);
```

I might also recommend switching your tween definition to `Phaser.Easing.Linear.None` instead of `'Linear'`, as I did above. It doesn't impact the functionality, but is something that might help you down the road.

Simple mistake, which is often the easiest to overlook. :)